# Curve recontruction using Velocity and Curvature

Tags: tracking, velocity, curve, kinematics

This might be a duplicate question, but I didn't get the conclusive answer in them.

I have the vehicle data  i.e., velocity (m/s), yaw rate(in radians), sampling times,  with these two I calculated the curvature of the road using the equation - curvature = YawRate/velocity.

mSec    Speed   YawRate(with offset 500)        Velocity

22  113     513     31.38888889

53  113     513     31.38888889

84  113     513     31.38888889

115 113     513     31.38888889

915 110     510     30.55555556

946 110     510     30.55555556

978 110     510     30.55555556

24  109     510     30.27777778

56  109     510     30.27777778

87  109     511     30.27777778

118 109     511     30.27777778

Now I want to plot the road **curvature** on an image of the road. I have the equation for curvature,

**Curvature = YawRate/Velocity)**

(something like showing the trail of the vehicle).
**Remember-I have to plot this trajectory on an image. How can I do it?

P:S at high speeds steering angle is not significant. so ruling out steering angle as input.

Comment: Clear the confusion you are doing between Velocity and Curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to plot are the known positions of the vehicle across time.

From the available data set we can infer that the polar coordinates are given by the **steering angle** (which seems to be absolute - deduct a quarter turn) and the instantaneous **radius of curvature**.

Convert from polar to Cartesian.

Without better information, you have to assume that the instantaneous center of rotation is fixed.

Comment: Yes, using instantaneous radius of curvature, how can I plot the track on  the image? Yes, I have to assume center of rotation as fixed.( I can call it as a point (x/2,0) )

Comment: Use a protractor and a ruler.